# Get content of a zk node that may be absent through ansible

Tags: ansible, apache-zookeeper

Using Ansible's [znode module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/znode_module.html), I'd like to get the content of a ZK node (which may be absent).

The official documentation merely state:

```
# Getting the value and stat structure for a znode
- znode:
    hosts: 'localhost:2181'
    name: /mypath
    op: get
```

I believe I need to `register:` the result in order to make any use of it. But what is the structure of this value? and what will happen if the node doesn't exist in zk?

NB: I plan to try, and post an answer here if I find out myself. In the meantime, if anyone already know how to do this, feel free to answer here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the specified node doesn't exist, the task will fail by default. This can of course be overridden by a `failed_when:`.

So, with the below playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks :
    - name: Get ZK node
      znode:
        hosts: "zk-server:2181"
        name: /my/zk/node
        op: get
      register: node
      failed_when: false
    - debug:
        var: node
```

I get the below output when the node doesn't exist:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "node": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "failed_when_result": false, 
        "msg": "The requested node does not exist."
    }
}
```

and I get this when the node exists:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "target_state": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "failed_when_result": false, 
        "msg": "The node was retrieved.", 
        "stat": {
            "acl_version": 0, 
            "aversion": 0, 
            "children_count": 0, 
            "children_version": 0, 
            "creation_transaction_id": 738760747521, 
            "ctime": 1564500556345, 
            "cversion": 0, 
            "czxid": 738760747521, 
            "dataLength": 12, 
            "data_length": 12, 
            "ephemeralOwner": 0, 
            "last_modified_transaction_id": 738760750645, 
            "mtime": 1564501388038, 
            "mzxid": 738760750645, 
            "numChildren": 0, 
            "pzxid": 738760747521, 
            "version": 1
        }, 
        "value": "Hello World!", 
        "znode": "/my/zk/node"
    }
}
```